# Optimizar select y option en javascrip

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

como puedo optimizar el siguiente script, es un script que funciona pero realmente estoy trabajando de forma estatica o con datos en duros, es posible realizar este script de manera mas eficiente y optimizada donde los "area_x" fueran automaticos del archivo php. Requiero que el botón Buscador pueda esconder los div que no estan selecionados en el select.

```
$("#Buscador").on('click',function() {  
var area = document.getElementById('area-interes').value;//selecciona el area
var div1 = document.getElementById('sec_1')
var div2 = document.getElementById('sec_2')

var divarea1 = document.getElementById('area_1')
var divarea2 = document.getElementById('area_2')
var divarea3 = document.getElementById('area_3')
var divarea4 = document.getElementById('area_4')


if (area =='area_1'){
    divarea1.style.display = 'block';
    divarea2.style.display = 'none';
    divarea3.style.display = 'none';
    divarea4.style.display = 'none';
}

if (area =='area_2'){
    divarea1.style.display = 'none';
    divarea2.style.display = 'block';
    divarea3.style.display = 'none';
    divarea4.style.display = 'none';
}

if (area =='area_3'){
    divarea1.style.display = 'none';
    divarea2.style.display = 'none';
    divarea3.style.display = 'block';
    divarea4.style.display = 'none';
}

if (area =='area_4'){
    divarea1.style.display = 'none';
    divarea2.style.display = 'none';
    divarea3.style.display = 'none';
    divarea4.style.display = 'block';
}

if (area =='area_0'){
    divarea1.style.display = 'block';
    divarea2.style.display = 'block';
    divarea3.style.display = 'block';
    divarea4.style.display = 'block';
}});
```

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta aunque se puede mejorar si enseñas mas parte de tu código e incluso si enseñas tu repositorio porque a primera vista es lo unico que podría hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para optimizar este codigo yo haria lo siguiente

```
let divAreas = document.querySelectorAll(".area");

function Foo(nameArea) {
  divAreas.forEach((area) => {
    if (area.value === "area_0") area.style.display = "block";
    area.value === nameArea
      ? (area.style.display = "block")
      : (area.style.display = "none");
  });
}

Foo("area_1");
```

En vez de crear un identificador para cada div, identificalos todos con un querySelectorAll y tomas el value y dentro de una funcion haces la logica con un forEach y un operador ternario.

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los casos, en vez de usar tanto If seria usar un switch

```
$("#Buscador").on('click',function() {  
    var area = document.getElementById('area-interes').value;//selecciona el area
    var div1 = document.getElementById('sec_1')
    var div2 = document.getElementById('sec_2')
    
    var divarea1 = document.getElementById('area_1')
    var divarea2 = document.getElementById('area_2')
    var divarea3 = document.getElementById('area_3')
    var divarea4 = document.getElementById('area_4')
    
 switch (area) {
    

case 'area_1' :
        divarea1.style.display = 'block';
        divarea2.style.display = 'none';
        divarea3.style.display = 'none';
        divarea4.style.display = 'none';
    
    
    break;
case 'area_2' :
        divarea1.style.display = 'none';
        divarea2.style.display = 'block';
        divarea3.style.display = 'none';
        divarea4.style.display = 'none';
    
    
    break;
case 'area_3' :
        divarea1.style.display = 'none';
        divarea2.style.display = 'none';
        divarea3.style.display = 'block';
        divarea4.style.display = 'none';
    
    
    break;
case 'area_4' :
        divarea1.style.display = 'none';
        divarea2.style.display = 'none';
        divarea3.style.display = 'none';
        divarea4.style.display = 'block';
    
    
    break;
case 'area_0' :
        divarea1.style.display = 'block';
        divarea2.style.display = 'block';
        divarea3.style.display = 'block';
        divarea4.style.display = 'block';
        break;
    }});
```